# How do I keep the screen contents after quitting less or more?

Tags: command-line, screen, less

After exiting from `less` or `more`, the screen contents are returned to what they were before. This happens with pagers like `less`/`more`, and some other commands. Sometimes it is necessary to keep the contents of the screen after one exits the command.

How can I make it so the text shown immediately before quitting the a program remains visible in the terminal afterwards?

Comment: This is a [`less` Frequently Asked Question](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html#tite).  And see http://superuser.com/a/715563/38062 for the opposite case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the -X switch:

```
-X or --no-init
          Disables  sending  the  termcap  initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal.
          This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something  unnecessary,  like
          clearing the screen.
```

Or you could do the following:
For example `cat myfile` to display the entire file or `cat myfile | grep searchterm` if you want to search for something specific.

You also could use `head -n X` or `tail-n X` to display the first/last X lines of a file.

Comment: yes, I can do that but what I want is to mantain the contents of the screen after what I have done with the command and not get the former contents back.

Comment: You can use the -X switch for less.

Comment: less -X and less --no-init did the job. Tks a lot.

Comment: You can use either, they both do the same.

Comment: Yes, Pabi. Now, I need the same (keep the screen contents) after quitting man or info. ¿Is it possible?

Comment: Just pipe it. `man man | less -X`

Comment: NO, Pabi. Maybe I'm not being clear. The thing is this: I execute a program (say less, more, man, info or some other). I see the output on the screen. When I reach the end or when I want to quit (by typing 'q') the screen contents is returned to what it was before I executed the program, but I want to keep the output of the program on the screen without having to send it to a file or piping it. Just like when I execute 'ls'. The output from it remains on the screen.

Comment: Not possible... You have to pipe it or make an alias for the pipe.

Comment: Note that this only works in the `LESS` variable for `man` if `LESS` is an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

less actually has -o options to save to file.

If you need to save output somewhere, specify it like so

`command | less -o outputfilename.txt`

What else you can do is `cat` output to file, if you need it, and then view that file. For instance `dmesg > text.txt; less text.txt`.